# AWS SAM yml to create API Gateway with methodresponse

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam, sam

I am able to create an API gateway in AWS using SAM. I am using this API Gateway to trigger a lambda. I need to return a response from API gateway by configuring MethodResponse through SAM.
Below is my SAM code:

```
MyApi:

    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api

    Properties:

      Name: 'MyAPI'

      StageName: !Ref Stage      




  MyLambda:

    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function

    Properties:      

      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler

      Runtime: python3.7          

      Events:

        MyApi:

          Type: Api

          Properties:

            RestApiId: !Ref MyApi

            Path: /abcde

            Method: POST
```

Expected (Look at method response):

[image]

[image]

But currently what I have using above SAM code is (Look at method response)

[image]